# Units of acceleration & Newton's 2nd Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, units

I tried to use Newton's second law, $F=ma$, to calculate the acceleration of an object.

\begin{align}\frac{F}{m}&=\frac{ma}{m} \\
a&=\frac{F}{m}=\frac{30\,\rm N}{1.2\,\rm kg}=25\rm\frac{N}{kg}\end{align}

Can acceleration have the denominator N/kg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave it at that, or you could note that the Newton has units of kg m/s$^2$:
$$
\frac{\rm N}{\rm kg}=\frac{\rm kg\,m/s^2}{\rm kg}=\frac{\rm m}{\rm s^2}
$$
which is your more typical way of writing accelerations.

Comment: When in doubt, break it down! NIST came up with a helpful for the relationship between derived and base SI units, see [here for the diagram](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/SIdiagram.html).